# Android: View backstack

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-studio-3.0

In the previous version of Android, one could view the backstack using the android profiler by selecting the "Graphics State" (as shown in pic). But, this seems to be absent in Android Studio 3.0.1. Does anyone know how to access this information now? I suspect that I sometimes cause duplicate activities to launch, and this would be SUPER useful to confirm it.

[image]

EDIT: 
OK, so I enabled the advanced profiler. It shows the different activities starting and stopping as the profile runs. I managed to see that there is indeed a duplicate activity (see image below, the red arrows show the two activities that have the same name but the short one never gets destroyed. The reason for this is that the user presses a button to start the activity - so double tapping creates two). It's really hard to pick up on (I had to zoom in like crazy), but I guess its something.

[image]

Comment: Please check my answer see if that is what you are searching.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the `memory issues` in `android studio 3.1.2` then they have changed the working of profiler a bit. Now you have to follow these steps:

- open `profiler` and start your application.
- Now click on the `memory line,` which is normally blue in color at least mine is.
- Now your `application` is running. Start `recording` button which is just above those all graphs. Button color is red.
- Keep doing the work while the profiler is recording the memory size/heap.
- When you want to finish just click the stop recording button and it will display you the results.

I have attached the image below too to give you the idea how it is done. You can select `Arrange by callStack` to see further options.

[image]

More you can find in the android documentation here [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

Comment: thank you for the fast response!! This isnt exactly what I was looking for. The Graphics state used to show you all the activities present in the backstack, so if there is a duplicate, you'd see it in this list. What I have done in the meantime is enable advanced profiling, there I could see two activities with the same name (and one not getting destroyed). Ill update the description above to demonstrate.

Comment: @Zee yeah I forgot to mention that you need to enable advance profiler too. But I will wait for your description now :)